# How to include CSS in mail template in core PHP?

Tags: php

I have created mail template in html

> test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Easy Donation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Easy Donation Receipt</h1>          
    </header>

    <h1>Thanks For Donating!</h1>
    <table class="donation-receipt">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name:</th>
            <td>{{test}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name:</th>
            <td>{{test}}</td>
        </tr>                       
    </table>
</body>
```

Internal CSS

```
<style>
body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

> mail.php

```
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "Example test";
$message = file_get_contents("test.html");
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

It is working fine I am getting mail but the style sheet (Internal CSS) is not applying in mail template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internal CSS? The css should be placed in the head of the html.

Comment: You need to add inline css like `<td style="border:1px solid red;">`

Comment: Please be clear, what do you mean by internal css?

Comment: I added style tag in test.html file below <html> </html> and I don't want to add inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution for that is to put your html code directly in a php variable like this:

```
$my_var = <<<EOT
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Easy Donation</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Easy Donation Receipt</h1>          
</header>

<h1>Thanks For Donating!</h1>
<table class="donation-receipt">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name:</th>
        <td>{{test}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name:</th>
        <td>{{test}}</td>
    </tr>                       
</table>
</body>
EOT;
```

It works all the time. Also just put your css in the head section.

Comment: how about using an external mailing service (sendgrid) rather than inbuilt php mail service. you just have to use their apis to initiate a mail. plus you can monitor additional mailing activities. it's easier and will enable you to send awesome templates. you just have to use the ids. On this case, using inline css seems to be the only solution....

Answer (score 0):

Try to write inline css.

Example:

```
<body style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 20px;display: inline-block;"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Internal CSS may not work in all mail portal, Therefore it is better way to add inline css as per requirement. It will work. For example:

```
<body style=" border: 1px solid black;" >

--Body element--
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any alternative solution, I don't want to add inline CSS.

Comment: You can use internal css  but put their Ids/class and then define css. It should work